# How to see the last line of code that caused the error with rider C++?

Tags: rider, jetbrains-rider

I have C++ code that caused crash of Unreal Engine. The problem when the error occurred Rider open assembly view , is there a way to see the last line of code that caused the error instead of assembly view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you have no Engine Debug symbols installed. Open Epic Games launcher, engine options, tick Editor symbols for debugging, select Apply. Wait while it downloads.

After that, reproduce the crash again while in the Debug mode.

[Symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUzOa.png)

[Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMyZN.png)